# Mplayer2 is mute, despite volume on the program and pulse being high

Tags: sound, mplayer

Once restart after installing and using correctly mplayer2, now I can't hear a thing, even when volume of the program and pulse is high. Other programs (i.e. clementine, cinnamon) I can hear correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong `-ao` device with Mplayer2. Available devices can be found as follows:

```
andrew@ilium~$ mplayer -ao help
MPlayer SVN-r37594-5.3.0 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
Available audio output drivers:
    alsa    ALSA-0.9.x-1.x audio output
    esd EsounD audio output
    pulse   PulseAudio audio output
    sdl SDLlib audio output
    mpegpes DVB audio output
    v4l2    V4L2 MPEG Audio Decoder output
    null    Null audio output
    pcm RAW PCM/WAVE file writer audio output
```

(I am testing this with MPlayer rather than MPlayer2 but there should be no difference.) Then experiment with each output device until you find one that works. For example: to test `alsa`:

```
mplayer -ao alsa input.m4a
```

with `input.m4a` being replaced with your actual audio filename. If `-ao alsa` is successful place this value in your config file in `~/.mplayer/config`:

```
ao=alsa
```

And then you should be good to go :)